# Upload Image In Laravel Project On Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel

It is My function to upload the image but the question is this why the images are not uploaded to public_html folder the images are uploaded in public folder of project.

```
private function upload($image, $tbl)
{
    $name    = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $newName = date('ymdgis') . $name;

    $image->move(public_path() . '/img' . $tbl, $newName);

    return $newName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `AppServiceProvider`  put this code on `register()` :

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('../public_html');
    });
}
```