# how to upload images in public_html not in project file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-7

I upload my Laravel app to C-panel, my public contents are in public_html and I change index.php on public to this :

```
require __DIR__.'/../thermotajhiz/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../thermotajhiz/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And other files in main root named *thermotajhiz*

Everything is ok but when I want to upload an image, instead of upload to public_html, a file with public name will create in *thermotajhiz* file outside the public_html

how can I fix this ?

I'm using this plugin for upload files :

[alexusmai/laravel-file-manager](https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-file-manager)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265175/4575350

Comment: @sta it's not work for me

Comment: You may also change `config/filesystems.php` configuration

Comment: yesterday i fixed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558162/laravel-wont-upload-file-to-public-html-but-instead-creating-folder-in-laravel/65558216#65558216   and change `'diskList' => ['public'],` to your custom disk https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-file-manager/blob/master/config/file-manager.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `config/filesystems.php` set like this

```
// Filesystem Disks
'disks' => [
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '../public_html',
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

],
```

if doesnt work try to change `../public_html` to `../../public_html` or `/home/yourcpanelusername/public_html`

and also make sure in your `config/file-manager.php` you set:

```
'leftDisk'  => 'public',
```

Comment: cpanel `'root' => /,` dir is not for public so it won't work

Comment: @KamleshPaul , I was wrong edit field, I updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I put this code to index.php instead of register method in AppServiceProvider and it's work :

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path('../public_html');
});
```

After this code :

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../thermotajhiz/bootstrap/app.php';
```